# Is __subclasses__() cached?

Tags: python, inheritance, sys

I have three models in three different files. 
The modules are all in `sys.path`

```
a.py:
class A(object):
    pass

b.py:
class B(A):
    passs

c.py:
class C(A):
    pass
```

Now I want to get the subclasses of A:

```
print A.__subclasses__()
>> [<class 'b.B'>, <class 'c.C'>]
```

So far so good.
But now I remove c.py from my sys.path and get the subclasses again. I would except, that there will be only `B` left.
But the output is the same:

```
# remove c.py from sys.pyth
sys.path.remove('../c')
print A.__subclasses__()
>> [<class 'b.B'>, <class 'c.C'>]
```

So somehow the `__subclasses__` call is cached. 
Is it possible to force `__subclasses__` to search sys.path again?

Comment: The module is still loaded even if you removed the file..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `class.__subclasses__()` is not cached, not really; the internal implementation uses weak references. But *modules* are; removing the `c.py` file will not unload the module.

You'd have to delete the module too:

```
import sys

del sys.modules['c']
```

and make sure to have no other references to the module.

Because classes involve a lot of references themselves (they point to their base classes, for starters) you need to make sure you run `gc.collect()` to make sure the deleted class objects are no longer retained in memory:

```
>>> class B(A): pass
... 
>>> A.__subclasses__()
[<class '__main__.B'>]
>>> del B
>>> A.__subclasses__()
[<class '__main__.B'>]
>>> gc.collect(0)
0
>>> gc.collect(1)
3
>>> gc.collect(1)
0
>>> gc.collect(2)
0
>>> A.__subclasses__()
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is incomplete, and unfortunately, the part you left out is the most important.  Let me correct your example:

**a.py:**

```
class A(object):
    pass
```

**b.py:**

```
from a import A    # you left this out
class B(A):
    passs
```

**c.py:**

```
from a import A    # you left this out
class C(A):
    pass
```

Once you `import` a module, *it remains imported*, unless you explictly unload it. Modifying `sys.path` will not affect the set of loaded modules.